# Jenkins: how would i bash script the initialAdminPassword set up for a dockerfile as opposed to pasting into the browser

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, terminal, dockerfile

Is it possible to bash script the setup process of jenkins, for example i have jenkins container set-up on my local machine, i would like to complete jenkins set-up entirely on bash for the purpose of scripting this entirely from a dockerfile.

I need to be able to pass initialAdminPassword without the use of a browser and just from the terminal.

Is it possible to complete the set-up from the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to skip the manual setup.
I don't know your particular setup, but let's assume you retrieve the password from jenkins instance :

```
cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

or

```
 docker exec "myjenkinscontainer" bash -c 'cat $JENKINS_HOME/secrets/initialAdminPassword'
```

You could then connect to Jenkins as admin, using that password. 
`curl --silent -u "admin:$mypassword" http://localhost:8080/manage`

If you've configured Jenkins Security to not allow API calls, then you might require to generate first a crumb token that you would use in every request, instead of the password. To issue a crumb token, you might do something similar :

`curl -s 'http://admin:$mypassword@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,\":\",//crumb)'`

Then you might need pass this crumb value instead of password in further requests.

Depending on your situation / Jenkins configuration, I might provide more details.